# Confusing VBA comment insertion behavior in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm going to rewrite this request. I see that I could be clearer.

From within the spreadsheet I highlight a cell where I want a standardized comment inserted. I use a keyboard shortcut to activate `AddServiceNote` and the code inserts a comment with standardized formatting and text.

Everything works, but it is not repeatable. I can't select another cell and add another comment using the same keyboard shortcut.

I can use another keyboard shortcut to activate `FormatNotes` where all the comments are formatted. Mysteriously, that reactivates my ability to insert another single standardized comment with `AddServiceNote`.

Am I missing something obvious? Why can't I insert comments over and over? Does this have to do with `Set Note = ActiveCell.Comment`?

```
Public Note As Comment

Public Sub AddServiceNote()
    If Note Is Nothing Then
        ActiveCell.AddComment
        Set Note = ActiveCell.Comment
        Note.Text "Function: "
        OrganizeElements
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub FormatNotes()
    For Each Note In ActiveSheet.Comments
        OrganizeElements
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub OrganizeElements()
     Note.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
     'and a long list of other attributes
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Whats happening is this:

- You have a Module Scope variable, `Note`.  Its value persists.
- The first time you run `AddServiceNote`, `Note Is Nothing` is TRUE, so the `If Then` code  runs
- In that `If` code, `Note` is `Set` to something
- The next time you run `AddServiceNote`, `Note Is Nothing` is FALSE, so the `If Then` code does *not* run
- Running `FormatNotes` executes a `For` loop, setting `Note` on each iteration
- After the last iteration of the `For` loop, `Note` is left as `Nothing` (that's a side effect of the `For`)
- So, having run `FormatNotes`, `AddServiceNote` will work again (once)

The fix is simple

- move the `Dim Note As ...` *inside* `AddServiceNote` (there is nothing about the code posted that required `Note` to be Module Scoped)
- Change `OrganizeElements`'s signature to
      `Public Sub OrganizeElements(Note As Comment)`
- Change the lines taht call `OrganizeElements` to pass `Note` as a parameter:
      `OrganizeElements Note`

```
Public Sub AddServiceNote()
    Dim Note As Comment

    If ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
        Set Note = ActiveCell.AddComment
        Note.Text Text:="Function: "
        OrganizeElements Note
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub FormatNotes()
    Dim Note As Comment
    For Each Note In ActiveSheet.Comments
        OrganizeElements Note
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub OrganizeElements(Note As Comment)
     Note.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
     'and a long list of other attributes
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. You got me trying things and thinking about my "Dim Note As". I decided to get rid of the variable and refer directly to the elements and that seems to have worked better. I eliminated all the "Set" commands. How do I refer to an individual comment if I am not using the variable in the "For Each" statement? I was using "For Each Note In ActiveSheet.Comments". What was "Note" referring to in the previous example? Cells.Comment?

Comment: @Mark I've refactored your code to demonstrate what I was saying

Answer (score 0):

Properly indenting the code makes it more obvious that the entirety of it in `Sub CommentAddLabor` only runs if there is no comment in the selected cell.

You want:

```
Public Sub CommentAddLabor()
    If Ct Is Nothing Then
        ActiveCell.AddComment
    End If
    Set Ct = ActiveCell.Comment
    CommentFormat 'calls the sub above
    Ct.Text "Function: " & Chr(10) & "Envision: " & Chr(10) & "Activity: " & Chr(10) & "Material: " & Chr(10) & "Duration: " & Chr(10) & "Consider: "
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had the End If at the bottom because the other items are also dependent on whether Ct is nothing. I completely rewrote my original posting to reduce the confusion of my request. If you could review that again it would be very much appreciated. Thank you again.